# VertScrollBox Detect when bottom reached android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have `GridLayout1` on a `VertScrollBox1`. The vertical scroll box scrolls through the content of the grid layout. I need to detect when the Vertical scroll box reach the bottom so I get to load more content to the grid layout. 
And do it again whenever bottom is reached again.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `OnViewportPositionChange()` of the `VertScrollBox1`. Then some simple arithmetics tell you when you are at the bottom:

```
uses Math, ...;
// ...

procedure TForm1.VertScrollBox1ViewportPositionChange(Sender: TObject;
  const OldViewportPosition, NewViewportPosition: TPointF;
  const ContentSizeChanged: Boolean);
begin
  if CompareValue(NewViewportPosition.Y, GridLayout1.Height - VertScrollBox1.Height) = EqualsValue then
    Memo1.Lines.Add('At bottom, time to grow and load more content to the GridLayout');
end;
```

Since the values we compare are floats, use `Math.CompareValue()` for comparison.

Alternatively `function SameValue()`, also in the `Math` unit

Comment: I guess you mean if comparevalue(NewViewportPosition.Y, GridLayout1.Height - VertScrollBox1.Height) ;)

Comment: i am very appreciated